# Relationship between variables

Tags: linear-algebra

Let’s say I have apples and oranges and depending on how many of each separately, there’s a total price. For example, 5 apples and 5 oranges are 20 dollars ; or 7 oranges and 3 apples are 21dollars (maybe oranges are worth more). Let’s say we create a table of prices based on amounts of each which could be Multiple columns.

Then let’s say there exists a different table of a combined total amount of apples and oranges with a total price. So in this table maybe 10 combined fruits equal $30 and decreases to the lower amounts and increases to higher amounts.

Is it possible to determine a relationship of some sort to go from the first table to the second table?

A better way to phrase this question or to describe it is putting it in terms of a matrix. Is it possible to find a solution for a mxm matrix such that the result is the mx1 vector. I know that it would be possible if an inverse existed. Let’s say it doesn’t. What would another approach be?

Number of apples vs number of oranges and the price in dollars to number of total fruits and their price in dollars.

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10           
1  x x x x x x x x x x x             1 X
2  x x x x x x x x x x x             2 X
3  x x x x x x x x x x x             3 X
4  x x x x x x x x x x x    To       4 X
5  x x x x x x x x x x x             5 X
6  x x x x x x x x x x x             6 X
7  x x x x x x x x x x x             7 X
8  x x x x x x x x x x x             8 X
9  x x x x x x x x x x x             9 X
10 x x x x x x x x x x x             10X
```

10x10 try to find a 10x1 such that it produces this 10x1 matrix.

I don’t have dollar amounts. This is just a hypothetical question and I’m wondering if it’s possible to solve if an inverse to the 10x10 matrix doesn’t exist

Comment: Do you mean an ecuation system?

Comment: Too much of what you have said is ambiguous sorry. As the saying goes, never do more work than the client.

Comment: A better way to phrase this question or to describe it is putting it in terms of a matrix. Is it possible to find a solution for a mxm matrix such that the result is the mx1 vector. I know that it would be possible if an inverse existed. Let’s say it doesn’t. What would another approach be?

Comment: The phrase "solution for a matrix" is a nonsense. Problems have solutions, equations have solutions, matrices don't have solutions. Is the situation that you have an equation $Ax=b$, where $A$ is a known matrix, $b$ is a known vector, and you want to find a vector $x$, but $A$ is not invertible? You can always use Gaussian elimination; in the underdetermined case, it will give you an infinite family of solutions, dependent on one or more parameters. In the overdetermined case, it won't give you any solution; then you can find a best approximate solution by the method of least squares.

Comment: I think that answers my question. Thank you Gerry! I will look into what an undetermined and determined case is as well as look into the method of least squares.

Comment: The terms are *underdetermined* and *overdetermined*.